# AWS Pinpoint Push Notifications and Apple Tracking Transparency

Tags: ios, react-native, tracking, aws-pinpoint, apptrackingtransparency

I have a short question - I am using AWS Pinpoint for push notification delivery in my React Native App that I am currently developing. Can I use Pinpoint for push notification delivery even if the user denies 3rd party tracking on iOS (Apple Tracking Transparency)? I mean I would solely want to use Pinpoint for delivering the pushs but Pinpoint is indeed also a tracking tool…

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks and best regards
The Smart Home Maker

Comment: any opinions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after more thoroughly studying the Apple App Tracking Transparency guidelines I see that if I only use tracking for myself but do not share information with other apps or websites, it is still allowed to track so there should also be no problem using AWS Pinpoint for push notification delivery even if the user declines app tracking.